# Semicolon in parameter of REST service call with Apache CXF 2.3

Tags: java, tomcat, rest, cxf, jax-rs

I'm try to pass parameter that contains semicolon(reserved symbol) in REST service, but I have problem with Apache Tomcat

REST services wrote using Apache CXF 2.3

```
@GET
@Path("/getCmBuildAreas/{productName}/{projectName}/{buildConfiguration}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public CmBuildAreas getCmBuildAreas(@PathParam("buildConfiguration") String buildConfiguration, @PathParam("productName") String productName, @PathParam("projectName") String projectName) {
...
}
```

Then I run query http://localhost:8080/DevManager/services/rest/getCmBuildAreas/QLARIUS/QLARIUS%3AMAINLINE_JAVA_STR/ANT_JAVA_BUILD%3B8 and received this error:

```
Jul 18, 2011 1:57:53 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils findTargetMethod
WARNING: No operation matching request path /DevManager/services/rest/getCmBuildAreas/QLARIUS/QLARIUS%3AAMAINLINE_JAVA_STR/ANT_JAVA_BUILD%3B8 is found, HTTP Method : GET, ContentType : */*, Accept : image/jpeg,application/x-ms-application,image/gif,application/xaml+xml,image/pjpeg,application/x-ms-xbap,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/msword,*/*,.
Jul 18, 2011 1:57:53 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: WebApplicationException has been caught : no cause is available
```

PS: if you need any additional information, ask.

Comment: How is `/getCmBuildConfigurations/{productName}/{projectName}` supposed to match `/getCmBuildAreas/QLARIUS/QLARIUS%3AMAINLINE_JAVA_STR/ANT_JAVA_BUILD%3B8` ?

Comment: I notice your URL has `getCmBuildAreas` and your `@Path` annotation has `getCmBuildConfigurations` - should these match?

Comment: Some error while copy-paste... Fixed

Comment: Why are you assuming that the problem is with the semilcolon? Does your service works when you call it with simpler parameters?

Comment: Yes, it work correctly even I pass colon(%3A) instead of %3B in ANT_JAVA_BUILD%3B8 parameter or without reserved parameters

Comment: Why are you encoding `;` to `%3B`? Semi-colon is a [perfectly valid character](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) and is used where the order of data isn't important (e.g. /product?sizes=8;9) as opposed to comma where order is important (e.g. /gps?coords=34,45).

Comment: `;` is a reserved character (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2) so it should be percent-encoded if he doesn't want it to be interpreted. I cannot understand why there would be a problem with it given that it works fine with the colon.

Comment: If i try not encode parameter buildConfiguration all information after semicolon is lost(pass "ANT_JAVA_BUILD;8" get "ANT_JAVA_BUILD"). It's very important to get "ANT_JAVA_BUILD;8" as one parameter of query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that Apache CXF 2.3 is not handling correctly encoded semicolons is due to a [BUG](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3404) in that version. It is fixed in versions 2.4, 2.3.4.

Comment: it’s broken in cxf 3.1.6…